# creating a class in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am learning objective-c and using xcode to develop a simple "single-view" app - so far I am dealing with the mainview.h and mainview.m and the xib files. My question is, I would like to create a class called "GetName" class, and put some methods in that class then call that class from my mainview.m?. How to do that in xcode and objective-c? Could you please give me a simple structure/example?

Comment: Look at this document http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.apple.com

or

`Xcode` ➜ `Menu` ➜ `Help` ➜ `Documentation and API Reference`.

Or simply: <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>?</kbd>

Comment: Yet, many times it's appropriate to send people to the docs.